# how to use ngModel in selector based tag?

Tags: angular, typescript

i am new for angular 2 i have one form that have multiple text box, checkbox, label and drop down 
if i use this control in my html then page makes very lengthy.
so i want make all control to separate component and then i want to use this component to selector based on my main component html.
but my question is that how would i use value of each of that control if i use 10 text box, 10 drop down and multiple label
any one have knowledge about that.

if i use ngmodel for that separate component then how i use it for each control

Comment: I think what you are looking for is ControlValueAccessor https://alligator.io/angular/custom-form-control/

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom your own custom component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-textinput',
  template: `<div class="form-group">
                    <label><ng-content></ng-content>
                        <input [(ngModel)]="value"
                                class="form-control"
                                (blur)="onBlur()" >
                    </label>
                </div>`,
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => TextInputCellEditorComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class TextInputCellEditorComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, OnInit, OnDestroy {

  private value: any;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    super();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    super.ngOnInit();
  }

  /**
   * Write value to the editor
   */
  public writeValue(value:any) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  /**
   * Register on change
   */
  public registerOnChange(fn) {

  }

  /**
   * Register on touch
   */
  public registerOnTouched(fn) {

  }

  ngOnDestroy() {

  }
}
```

And then you can use this component in your application

```
<form>
    <my-textinput name="anyValue"
                  [(ngModel)]="anyModel">
    </my-textinput>
  </form>
```